# Fill table cell with horizontal css menu

Tags: html, css

I have a css menu (the source for which I downloaded because I don't know squat about css) contained in a div

```
<div id='cssmenu' style='float:right;'>
  <ul>
    <li id='index'><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li id='aboutus'><a href='aboutus.php'><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    <li id='gallery'><a href='gallery.php'><span>Galley</span></a></li>
    <li id='videos'><a href='videos.php'><span>Videos</span></a></li>
    <li id='links'><a href='links.php'><span>Links</span></a></li>
    <li id='contact'><a href='contact.php'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have this inside of a `<td>` with a fixed width (let's say 500px for simplicity).  I adjusted the padding in the css to get the width to fit nicely... at least in Firefox.  When I look at it in Chrome, the last menu item overflows the width of the table cell and ends up below the rest of the menu.

My question is, how do I make the menu items equally spaced across the width of the table?  setting padding to 0px makes everything look tiny and squished, and I still want the vertical padding.

here is my css (sorry, I know it's long)

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding:0px;
  display:table;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li a {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #222222;
  /* Old browsers */

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #222222 50%, #3c3c3c 51%, #393939 78%, #888888 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #222222 50%, #3c3c3c 51%, #393939 78%, #888888 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #222222 50%, #3c3c3c 51%, #393939 78%, #888888 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #222222 50%, #3c3c3c 51%, #393939 78%, #888888 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000000 0%, #222222 50%, #3c3c3c 51%, #393939 78%, #888888 100%);
  width: 100%;
  display:table-row-group;
}
#cssmenu:after
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*width: auto; */
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #222222 61%, #222222 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #222222 61%, #222222 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #222222 61%, #222222 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #222222 61%, #222222 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  z-index: 3;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.active {
  background: #1275ae;
  /* Old browsers */

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0b4669 0%, #1275ae 50%, #1794dc 51%, #1691d8 78%, #98d2f4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0b4669 0%, #1275ae 50%, #1794dc 51%, #1691d8 78%, #98d2f4 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0b4669 0%, #1275ae 50%, #1794dc 51%, #1691d8 78%, #98d2f4 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #0b4669 0%, #1275ae 50%, #1794dc 51%, #1691d8 78%, #98d2f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0b4669 0%, #1275ae 50%, #1794dc 51%, #1691d8 78%, #98d2f4 100%);
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover::after,
#cssmenu ul li.active::after {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #1275ae 61%, #1275ae 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #1275ae 61%, #1275ae 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #1275ae 61%, #1275ae 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, #1275ae 61%, #1275ae 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy if you are using table, but here you have ul so i suggest you to use calc() function if you can comfort with it. or wait for some another solution. I have tested it with your code like width: calc(100%/ 6); and it works great.

I had add this rule to #cssmenu ul li

Comment: If he has this menu inside a table, why not just make the men a table as well.

Comment: I added width: calc(500px/6); to #cssmenu ul li a {} and that seems to be working.  I'm up voting your answer for pointing me in the right direction, but not marking it as accepted because it wasn't quite the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ul{
display:table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
li{
    display:table-cell;
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/upj6oe0z/

I hope it works.